# php include and include_once

Tags: php

really quick question does php 5 still support include_once because I am getting some unusual characters "..." when I use include_once but not when I use include

Comment: Can you post does error lines that you get ?

Comment: the only error is .... were the include should be when viewing the source on a live server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"..." is not a PHP error message. Any other symptoms?

Btw you could use include if you go for performance.

Comment: no just "..." it must be in the php code but I cannot for the life of my see it. I basically comment out all the includes but any 1 include and it fixes the bug but soon as I use to includes it comes back.

Comment: I'm really curious about how this answer fixed the issue...

Answer (score 1):

The only change between 4 and 5 is as follows (from PHP.net)

> This behaviour changed in PHP 5, so for example with Windows the path is normalized first so that C:\PROGRA~1\A.php is realized the same as C:\Program Files\a.php and the file is included just once.

[PHP.net - include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)

So to answer your question, yes PHP 5 supports include_once